# My keyboard swaps comma for fullstop, but only when using MS Excel or W10 Calculator

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, csv

So, if I enter a dollar value, for instance, it enters into Excel as $123,45 not $123.45. As you can imagine, this causes havoc with csv files. If I use the `.(>)` key above Alt, Excel won't do math with the number, treats it as text :~

In Calculator, the `.(>)` key above Alt does not work at all, but the `.(Del)` key over on my number pad does - as a comma, not a `.`

So, excel won't do math with my values because the comma confuses it, and Calc gives me answers that are thousands more than expected, although the correct digits for me to manually assign where the decimal point goes.

I'm a bit lost as to why, and therefore how to fix

Comment: Change the options in Excel for decimal separator and Thousand separator

Comment: because your locale uses comma as a radix point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically happens when the regional settings and formats have been changed from the default. Excel takes its decimal character from the regional settings of the computer (and I would assume that the calculator does the same thing).

Check the regional settings in Windows 10 and set them for the defaults for your country.

If you personally don't want to use these defaults, then you can instruct Excel to use different characters for decimal point and thousand separator.

When you work with CSV files, you can use the settings in the Import wizard to align the conventions of the CSV file with the conventions you want to use.

Comment: Yes, even though Windows 10 said English NZ, it had , as a decimal separator. I had to go into 'Advanced Settings' and there it was.

Comment: Glad to help out a fellow Kiwi.